# Laravel 5.8 create a recursive collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table that contains branches, departments and teams.  A branch can have many departments, and a department can have many teams. The class is called 'Organisation`.

The `organisations` table:

```
id    parent_id   type   name
1     null        b      Branch1 
2     null        b      Branch2
3     1           d      Dep1
4     2           d      Dep2
5     3           t      Team1
6     4           t      Team2
```

I am trying to generate a method in the class that will recursively return all children records for a given position in the tree.

I have a relationship up called `children`:

```
/**
 * Children
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Organisation::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I have created a method called `tree` in the class as follows:

```
/**
 * Organisation Tree
 */
public function tree()
{
    $merged = new Collection;

    foreach($this->children as $child) {
        $merged->merge($child->tree());
    }

    return $merged;
}
```

So for example:

```
$o = Organisation::find(1);

$treeCollection = $o->tree();
```

And the `$treeCollection` should contain:

```
id    parent_id   type   name
1     null        b      Branch1 
3     1           d      Dep1
4     3           t      Team1
```

But the above method returns and empty collection and it does not fail. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
/**
 * Organisation Tree
 */
public function tree()
{
    $merged = new Collection;

    $merged = $merged->merge($this->children);

    foreach($this->children as $child) {
        $merged = $merged->merge($child->tree());
    }

    return $merged;
}
```